# How can I make SonarQube ignore generic exception?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sometimes, I don't what exception will catch, so I use Exception rather than dedicate exception. When I use sonarQube to check the code quality of my project, and sonarQube always reports generic exception should be avoided, use the dedicate one instead.

So how to make SonarQube ignore generic Exception check?

Comment: You can disable the rule in Sonar. Just deactivate it in the quality profile settings. If you use the root profile, you will have to create a copy first. But first you should be sure you understand why that quality check is there and if it's really a good idea to ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `//NOSONAR` on any offending line to ignore a wide range of sonar issues.

Source: [Sonar FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/faq/).